# Docker CA Cert Issue on docker login

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, docker, ssl-certificate

Please note before marking this as a duplicate, this question HAS been asked elsewhere but the answers provided are not solving my problem.

I am following the instructions at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

I am trying to set up a docker registry on Ubuntu 18.06 that may be accessed from another PC (windows).  The connection is encrypted with an ssl certificate obtained from letsencrypt. 
I run the registry like this:

```
docker run -d \
  --restart=always \
  --name registry \
  -v "$(pwd)"/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_ADDR=0.0.0.0:443 \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/certificate.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/private.key \
  -p 443:443 \
  registry:2
```

This works beautifully and my remote system can push images to my new repo, no problem.

As the instructions above say, I have created the following:

```
/etc/docker/certs.d/<my-host>:<my-port>
    - ca_bundle.crt
    - certificate.crt
    - private.key
```

The problem is that I cannot reach the repo from the local machine.  Upon attempting to log in, I get the following error:

```
$ docker login <my-host>:<my-port>
docker: Error response from daemon: open /etc/docker/certs.d/<my-host>:<my-port>: permission denied.
```

It's like it is looking in the right place but can't read the file but I can't figure out why.  Permissions look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug  5 01:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Aug  5 01:44 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1646 Aug  5 01:43 ca_bundle.crt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1906 Aug  5 01:43 certificate.crt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1703 Aug  5 01:43 private.key
```

All permissions should be right.  Just in case it was trying to read that location as a file rather than a directory, I also tried a variant on this where I renamed my ca_bundle.crt as a file rather than a directory, at /etc/docker/certs.d/:.crt.  When I do that, I get an error stating that "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority", indicating that it cannot find any cert.

Again, I can perform this login on my remote Windows system without any problems whatsoever.  It's only when I try to login on my local docker (in order to pull the image that was pushed up remotely, to run it) that it fails.

I have also tried the following:
1) Adding the certs under /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
2) sudo update-ca-certificates

Just in case it makes a difference, I have been restarting docker each and every time I make a change.

Comment: Not sure it is the reason but the fact that you cert key is readable by everyone is possibly a problem. Certificates usually need to be accessible only by the owner (`-rw-------`), otherwise they are considered compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem here, using docker with snap. A look into the `/var/log/syslog` showed me issues with apparmor.

```
Aug 14 10:21:53 xxx kernel: [52828.220295] audit: type=1400 audit(1565770913.719:675): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/etc/docker/certs.d/my-repo/" pid=28197 comm="dockerd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

That's why the certs have to be placed in `/var/snap/docker/common/etc/certs.d` instead of `/etc/docker/certs.d` as written in the docker [snap documentation](https://github.com/docker/docker-snap/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I've placed certificates in that folder, but keep getting errors. In my case AppArmors says:
`audit: type=1400 audit(1579610136.218:267): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.docker" name="/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/hpage_pmd_size" pid=16571 comm="docker" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0`